# Intermittently org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash" for Chrome 57 and chromedriver 2.29

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, session

Our Selenium automation testcases were running fine but since we upgraded to Chrome 57 and chromedriver 2.29, our automation suite constantly skips executing testcases. Seeing this issue with Selenium 3.0 and 3.3.1 both. Out of 10 times hitting automation, 8 times page crashes and skips all automation tests.

The failure log shows "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash".

Error:

```
1910745 [main] INFO  com.zimbra.qa.selenium.framework.ui.AbsSeleniumObject  - getElementById(ZLoginButton)
1910831 [main] INFO  com.zimbra.qa.selenium.framework.ui.AbsSeleniumObject  - getElementById()org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: unknown error: session deleted because of page crash
from unknown error: cannot determine loading status
from tab crashed
  (Session info: chrome=57.0.2987.133)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 83 milliseconds
Build info: version: '3.3.1', revision: '5234b32', time: '2017-03-10 09:04:52 -0800'
```

Comment: Try reverting to chromedriver v2.28 with selenium 3.3.1

Comment: Can you crosscheck with Firefox browser once? Then we can find the root cause.

Comment: I am having the same problem with Chrome Version 58.0.3029.96, ChromeDriver 2.29 and Selenium.Webdriver 3.4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have checked this issue for running tests about 50 hours constantly on Chrome browser and things are quite fine now. I won't say this is the solution because Chrome driver itself fixed this issue. As far as testing we did, it works fine using latest selenium 3.6.0 and chrome driver 2.33 so would like post as an answer just to close this issue.

Chrome 61, Selenium 3.6.0 and Chrome driver 2.33 combinations looks very good and far stable than before to use for running automation tests on complex application which runs for long hours.

```
Chrome version: 61.0

chromeDriverURL=http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.33:

<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-api" rev="3.6.0"/>
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-chrome-driver" rev="3.6.0"/>
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-edge-driver" rev="3.6.0"/>
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-firefox-driver" rev="3.6.0"/>
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-ie-driver" rev="3.6.0"/>
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-java" rev="3.6.0"/>
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-remote-driver" rev="3.6.0"/>
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-safari-driver" rev="3.6.0"/>
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-server" rev="3.6.0"/>
<dependency org="org.seleniumhq.selenium" name="selenium-support" rev="3.6.0"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue. You can directly go to the Task Manager and kill all the instances of Chromedriver.

It will solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

I can assure that reverting to the 2.28 driver with selenium 3.3.1 does not work. In fact, I had that configuration previously amd upgraded the driver to the 2.29, but with the same issue. It's extremely annoying.

This happens with Firefox as well, but less often.

Sorry for the bad news, but I think Selenium is the problem.

The best way to solve this is to use Selenium version (both for the selenium driver and the remote driver) 3.0.1

Below the dependencies from Maven:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I don't think Selenium is the issue either. We're using 2.53 and just now also started encountering this problem.